# Hay alguna forma de seleccionar números en un vector

Tags: java

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx1pt.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx1pt.jpg)Quisiera saber como selecccionar un número dentro de un vector un Nunero N de veces en caso de repetirse

Intente hacer un arreglo dimensional y si puedo elegirlo pero solo una vez y en mi programa se repite más y quisiera mostrar eso

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rd = new Random();
    //declaramos el vector
    System.out.println("introduzca el tamaño del vector");
    int tam=sc.nextInt();
    int[]vector= new int[tam];
    //mostramos contenido del vector
    System.out.println("contenido del vector");
for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
    vector[i]=rd.nextInt(5 - 1)+1;
    System.out.println("["+i+"]="+vector[i]);
}
int pos=-1;
    System.out.println("introduzca el numero que desee ver cuanto se repite");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int acum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
        if(vector[i]==n){
            pos=i;
            acum+=pos;
            
        }
    }
        if(pos==-1){
            System.out.println("no se encontro el numero");
            
        
                
                }else{
            System.out.println("la poscion  "+n+"es el indice [ "+acum +"]");
        }
    }
```

Comment: agrega el codigo que ya tengas hecho

Comment: copia y pega el codigo no adjuntes imagen [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/567298/edit)

Comment: lo que queres es ver cuantas veces se repite un numero dentro de un vector?

Comment: si, y que a su vez me muestre en cuales indices se repite el numero

Answer (score 0):

Después de generar los números en el vector, lo que necesitas hacer es recorrer el vector generado y comparar cada elemento con el número a buscar, si el numero se encuentra en algún indicé del vector tienes que guardar el índice donde fue encontrado, para ello puedes hacer uso del [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) que es un arreglo dinámico.

```
    ArrayList<Integer>indices=new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("introduzca el numero que desee ver cuanto se repite");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int acum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
        if(vector[i]==n){
            indices.add(i);
            acum++;            
        }
    }
```

Finalmente sólo queda mostrar si se encontraron el número buscado dentro del vector

```
   if(acum==0){
        System.out.println("no se encontro el numero"); 
    }else{
        System.out.println("Se encontró "+acum+" veces"+" el número "+n);
        System.out.println("Los indices son: "+indices.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

En este ejemplo no voy a usar el teclado para introducir los numeros al vector, pero la logica te va a servir igual:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Prueba{
    
  static void findNumber(Vector<Integer> vector, Integer number){ // funcion estatica de la clase Prueba, pasamos el vector y el numero a buscar
    Integer count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<vector.size();i++){
      if(vector.get(i)==number){ // get nos da el elemento en el indice pasado por parametros
        System.out.println("coincidencia encontrada en el indice " + i); // imprimo el indice de la coincidencia
        count++; // incrementamos
      }
    }
    if(count<=0)  System.out.println("no se han encontrado coincidencias"); // imprimimos el contador en caso de que sea mayor a 0
    else System.out.println("se han encontrado un total de " + count + " coincidencias");      
  }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Vector<Integer> myvector = new Vector<Integer>(20); // en mi caso uso el objeto Vector
        myvector.add(12);
        myvector.add(11);
        myvector.add(2);
        myvector.add(9);
        myvector.add(13);
        myvector.add(11);
        myvector.add(34);
        myvector.add(61);
        myvector.add(19);
        myvector.add(64);
        myvector.add(11);
        myvector.add(90);
        myvector.add(73);
        myvector.add(51);
        myvector.add(57);
        myvector.add(2);
        myvector.add(88); // añado varios numeros

        Prueba.findNumber(myvector, 11); // llamo a la funcion buscadora

    }
}
```

Comment: no entiendo que tiene de malo la respuesta?

Comment: si van a dar votos negativos al menos aclaren porque